# Laravel Relationships - Select rows with same column value in blade

Tags: laravel, relationships

Let's say I have a post with many comments and I properly  defined `$post->comments` relation in my post model. Comments have a column named `confirmed` with the value of `0` or `1`. How can I select confirmed (rows which have confirmed value of `1`) rows in my blade template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help you 
In your Post model

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment:class);
}

public function confirmedComments()
{
    return $this->comments()->whereConfirmed(1);
}
```

And from your controller

```
$comments = $post->confirmedComments;
```

If in blade, you want select confirmed comments, it's so easy to do it with

```
@if($comment->confirmed)
    //confirmed comment
@else
   //
@endif
```

Hope it'll be helpful !

Comment: I think `confirmedComment()` should be a query scope. [Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes)

Comment: @RamyHerrira May be of course, but if he wants to retrieve comments from instance of Post — e.g `$post = Post::findOrFail($id);`, and get comments of `$post`— query scopes will not be the best on this situation

Comment: @Goms Yes of course but sorry I didn't explain myself clearly. I was talking about a local scope `confirmed` in the `Comment` model. This way we would have `$post->comments()->confirmed()`. I think this is a more 'eloquent' way and it's beneficial in cases like code refactoring and reuse.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

If you already have the `comments` eager loaded, then you can use the `where()` method on the `comments` collection:

```
$confirmedComments = $post->comments->where('confirmed', 1);
```

This will go through all the comments in the collection and only return those that are confirmed.

If you don't have the existing collection, you can add the where clause to the relationship query. This way, you're only getting confirmed comments from the database, and you're not wasting resources retrieving and building models for comments you're not using

```
$confirmedComments = $post->comments()->where('confirmed', 1)->get();
```

And, another option, would be to create a new relationship for just confirmed comments, and that way you can eager load the new relationship:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comments::class);
}

public function confirmedComments()
{
    return $this->comments()->where('confirmed', 1);
}

$confirmedComments = $post->confirmedComments;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.